# Criteria api - illegalStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I've written following code by using Criteria Api:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = criteriaQuery.from(Entity.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));

Long countOfRows = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

As a result I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were
>   specified

The exception is thrown by **getSingleResult** method (last line of the code). Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after forcing **countQuery** to add root:

```
((QueryStructure)((CriteriaQueryImpl)countQuery).queryStructure).roots.add(root)
```